# Mocking a @Bean defined in a @ConfigurationProperties Class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a @ConfigurationProperties class like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprops", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
@Configuration
public class MyProperties {

   private Long mySchedulerRate;

   @Bean
   public Long mySchedulerRate() {
       return this.mySchedulerRate;
   } 

}
```

I'm registering it as a bean so I can refer to it in an annotation for a Spring scheduler:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{@mySchedulerRate}")
public void runScheduledUpdate() {
   ...
{
```

However, I now want to write a unit test where I want to be able to set a different value for the bean 'mySchedulerRate'. Mocking/Spying on the @ConfigurationProperties class doesnt seem to work since the scheduler gets set up before the stubbing has been set to return my desired value.

What is the easiest way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: what exactly u want to test? according to the code above mySchedulerRate has nothing expect for a Long value

Comment: I want the value of that Long bean to be different in one particular test so I was trying to change the value of the bean. What Im trying to test isnt super relevant to the issue.

Comment: try to declare this value in application.properties under test folder. so that when u test, that value will be taken

Comment: Yeah but I want it to only be different for this one particular test and all the others I want it to be something else.

Comment: Is it a test with a Spring runner or a Mockito runner ? Showing your actual test would be a good start.

Comment: Okay. Did you try using `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` or `TestPropertySource`

Comment: Yeah, apologies, I should have added more details for the test runner. I've actually managed to fix it now Ill post the answer. Sorry for wasting peoples time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to fix this now. I was running a @SpringBootTest and I realise you can override properties here within the annotation for a particular test class.

This worked for me:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class, properties = "myprops.my-scheduler-rate=1000")
public class MyTest {
```

So no need to try and override the bean, I was overcomplicating this far too much.

Comment: I waited for your answer to propose this way if you used a Spring Runner. Finally, you found it alone fast :) Great

Comment: Its not usual for me to give up and ask SO but I was banging my head until just now! Bit late on a Friday for me I think. I'll try repay you for your time anyway :)

Comment: Sometimes, the light comes a little late :) You are kind. Anyway, good answer.